# Sharepoint 2013 Add-ins javascript on install

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like to know if Sharpoint 2013 hosted-apps support running a script (javascript) once when installed ... for settings security and provisionning

I've found some blogs about that but dont find any good practice, i dont want to load the provisionning javascript each time the default.aspx page is loaded

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is JavaScript support for add in installed/uninstalling and upgraded events. However, Both SharePoint-hosted and provider-hosted add in support a RemoteEvent Web Service for add in installed/uninstalling and Upgraded events. The remote event web service can contain the provisioning logics and has to be hosted on a hosting environment. 
If you are really looking for JavaScript approach, you might create one and code it to run provisioning logic just once. But as add in model introduced and I would recommend to put your provisioning logic into PS.

I hope it helps.